# InfluxDB returns empty result set when querying a specific date

Tags: influxdb

Querying `influxDB` (one or multiple day data) seems fine in most cases, except when including a specific date (5th of January) as part of the time range.

Example queries that work fine (they all return data):

```
select * from "measurements" where time >= '2020-01-07T23:00:00.000Z' and time <  '2020-01-08T23:00:00.000Z'

select * from "measurements" where time >= '2020-01-08T23:00:00.000Z' and time <  '2020-01-09T23:00:00.000Z'

select * from "measurements" where time >= '2020-01-07T23:00:00.000Z' and time <  '2020-01-12T23:00:00.000Z'
```

Example queries that **don't work**: Result set is empty, and logs show status code 200, although I am sure there is data (based on the queries above):

```
select * from "measurements" where time >= '2020-01-05T23:00:00.000Z' and time <  '2020-01-06T23:00:00.000Z'

select * from "measurements" where time >= '2020-01-05T23:00:00.000Z' and time <  '2020-01-07T23:00:00.000Z'

select * from "measurements" where time >= '2020-01-05T23:00:00.000Z' and time <  '2020-01-12T23:00:00.000Z'
```

Basically, when I include **`2020-01-05T23:00:00.000Z`** as my beginning timestamp, all result sets are empty.

Could it be that my DB is corrupted? What can I do to fix this?

Comment: It's really hard to reproduce this example. Can you provide how you add the data, which version if InfluxDB are you using and other such useful details?